# How can I retrieve Qiskit Runtime jobs that I have submitted to IBM Quantum?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, qiskit-runtime

I have submitted Qiskit Runtime jobs. How can I retrieve the old jobs to check the status and results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the list of Qiskit Runtime jobs under [`Program jobs` tab in the `Jobs` page](https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/jobs?jobs=runtime) on IBM Quantum platform.

[image: Program jobs]

From there you can find the **job id** and the corresponding **provider** information (in `HUB_NAME/GROUP_NAME/PROJECT_NAME` format and the default provider is `ibm-q/open/main`) to retrieve the job using Qiskit on IBM Quantum Lab or on your local Jupyter environment using the following code.

Note that runtime job id starts with letter `c` while ordinary circuit job id start with a number, usually `6`.

```python
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService

service = QiskitRuntimeService()
 
job = service.job("JOB_ID")
```