# How to access a qiskit runtime job and query time_taken?

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, qiskit-runtime

I am trying to execute qiskit runtime jobs on simulators and real machines and I would like to extract information about the time taken to execute each runtime job. Since using python `time.time()` method will include also queueing time, which I would like to exclude, I thought about checking on `time_taken` attribute of the `RuntimeJob`. To this end, I found this code:

```
job = provider.runtime.run(program_id='...', inputs=inputs, options=options)
job_id = job.job_id()
job_info = backend.retrieve_job(job_id)
```

And my plan was to use the `time_taken` attribute, as I have seen in many other threads.
However, I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/dist-packages/qiskit/providers/ibmq/ibmqbackendservice.py", line 484, in retrieve_job
    raise IBMQBackendApiError('Failed to get job {}: {}'
qiskit.providers.ibmq.exceptions.IBMQBackendApiError: "Failed to get job c8s4h14o112vg1vn8ed0: '404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://api-qcon.quantum-computing.ibm.com/api/Network/.../main/Jobs/c8s4h14o112vg1vn8ed0/v/1. Job not found., Error code: 3250.'
```

I checked the id in the IBM quantum service web interface, and the `job_id` is the same. I do not understand what I am doing wrong. Is there something I am missing?

Until now, that's the best I could do, but I am sure there is a better way:

```
job = provider.runtime.run(program_id='x', inputs=inputs, options=options)
while job.status() != JobStatus.RUNNING:
    pass
start = time.time()
res = job.result()
end = time.time()
```

Thanks a lot for your attention and Best Regards!

Comment: I think the problem you are facing is due to the difference of retrieving jobs for normal circuit job vs runtime job. For runtime job, you should use this code `job = provider.runtime.job('JOB_ID')` See more details here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/23637/how-can-i-retrieve-qiskit-runtime-jobs-that-i-have-submitted-to-ibm-quantum

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I just have a question : since your job is already stocked in the variable `job` when you call `job = provider.runtime.run(program_id='...', inputs=inputs, options=options)`, then why try to retrieve it right after? It is not necessary here since you run it right before.

Now, to retrieve a runtime job, you have to do this :

```
job_id='your_jobid'
job = provider.runtime.job(job_id)
```

Btw, the time taken by the job might have another name based on the program you run. For example it will still be `time_taken` for `circuit_runner`, but for QAOA or VQE it will be called `optimizer_time`.

Comment: And optimizer time can be extracted from the result using `job.result()['optimizer_time']`